# Adding Bootstrap tables to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, datatables, bootstrap-table

I'd like to use [Bootstrap Tables](https://bootstrap-table.com) with WordPress, mainly because Tablepress is ugly and adds tables using shortcodes, meaning the data is lost on uninstall. However, I am not sure how to go about it. Is it just a matter of adding the CSS and JS links to the head and footer of my site's templates? I am interested in using the Materialise theme.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to create some custom tables in your theme without a plugin.

You may need to create custom plugins or a custom template for the same. You can use the bootstrap table CDN in your functions.php, or you can import it directly from the template.

You can create your own template just refer : [Page Templates - WordPress Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

and import

**CSS BS Table**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
```

**JS BS Table**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can simply make the table in the template_name.php using Bootstrap Table

===========================UPDATE=============================

You could simply link the CSS and js to your theme's " header.php " using `<link>` Tag

or

Enqueue through the functions.php like

```
function add_theme_scripts() {
  
  wp_enqueue_style( 'slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/slider.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');
 
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

Now you can use the BS Table classes anywhere. You just have to format or add the table in your Post Page as HTML. Use the BS CSS classes in the HTML Block of your post and construct the table.

You need to make the necessary changes if you were using dynamic tables or tables populated with other plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am still lost. I would like the styles to apply in tables created in normal posts; how would I go about creating custom tables for that? Since I want to use Materialise CSS, I wondered if I should add their table styles to a child css file, and then import the Bootstrap CSS and JS. That is assuming I didn't just do two, as I asked in my first question. 

Hopelessly lost.